# Android OrientationEventListener not displaying right mode

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have created orientation detection function, but it is not working properly, I need to get notification when orientation changed left or right. I specifically made this with OrientationEventListener because I do not wish to use OnConfigurationChanged because of reasons.

```
int orentation; // 0 - Portariat; 1 - Right; 2 - Left
int new_orentation;

orentation = 0;
new_orentation = 0;

myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {

            orent.setText("Orientation: " + String.valueOf(arg0));


            switch (orentation) {
            case 0:

                if (arg0 > 60)
                    new_orentation = 1;

                else if (arg0 < 300) 
                    new_orentation = 2;

                break;
            case 1:

                if (arg0 < 30)
                    new_orentation = 0;

                else if (arg0 < 300) 
                    new_orentation = 2;

                break;
            case 2:

                if (arg0 > 330)
                    new_orentation = 0;

                else if (arg0 > 300) 
                    new_orentation = 1;

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            if (orentation!=new_orentation) 
            {
                switch (new_orentation) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Normal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                orentation = new_orentation; 
            }



        }};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that the param declares difference but absolute position.  It seems it should be something like the switch/case you are using is not appropriate.  Maybe something more like (adjust accordingly for how you want to exactly define each case):

```
if(arg0 <= 90){
  new_orentation = 1;
}
else if(arg0 <=180){
  //this is reversePortrait
  new_orentation = 0;
}
else if(arg0 <= 270){
  new_orentation = 2;
}
else{
  new_orentation = 0;
}
```